# Use a library as a #lang?

Tags: racket

I have a few files that start like this:

```
#lang racket/base
(require "my-library.rkt")
```

I would be very happy if I could start my files with:

```
#lang my-library
```

Is it possible to use a library as a `#lang`? What changes would I need to make to `my-library.rkt`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, create `my-library/lang/reader.rkt` with the following:

```
#lang s-exp syntax/module-reader
my-library
```

Then, add the following to `my-library.rkt`:

```
(provide (all-from-out racket/base))
```

You can read about [`syntax/module-reader`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/syntax_module-reader.html) for more details on how to use it.

Comment: Note: it's also possible to [use a submodule](http://blog.racket-lang.org/2012/06/submodules.html) for the reader module in cases where that's easier than defining a separate lang directory.

Answer (score 6):

If your library isn't going to do anything "lang like", and you merely want to eliminate the `require`?  You could:

1. Change `my-library.rkt` as Chris describes: Add `(provide (all-from-out racket/base))`. But don't bother creating any `my-library/lang/reader.rkt` file.
2. To use it: `#lang s-exp "my-library.rkt"`.  Note the `s-exp`, so technically this doesn't answer your question exactly. :)

Keep in mind that you can shadow bindings in `my-library.rkt` now that it's being used as a lang instead of being `require`d.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add to Chris's answer. You can also set up the `#lang` so that it works like a built in one:

```
#lang my-library
```

To do this, you'll need to set up a package. The easiest way to get a package is with `raco pkg new`.

Type in:

```
raco pkg new my-library
```

And replace the template with your library.

Then, in the root of your package, add a folder and file called: `lang/reader.rkt` And in that file put:

```
#lang s-exp syntax/module-reader
my-library
```

Now, install the package (from the root of your folder, run `raco pkg install`, and you should now be able to use your language as if it was built in to racket.

As Chris said, you might want to make sure that you add to your library:

```
(provide (all-from-out racket/base))
```

To make sure you have `racket/base` bindings in your new language. Although if you don't want the `racket/base` bindings in there, then you can leave them out.

Finally, you can upload your new fancy language to the package server So that other people can download it. Here is the [documentation for it](http://docs.racket-lang.org/pkg/Package_Concepts.html?q=package#%28tech._package%29), but I recommend you just upload it to github, and copy what some other packages do.

Comment: This is a bad answer: it manages to maximize the amount of hassle needed for something that should be simple.  That's why Greg's answer should be the proper solution, then Chris's answer should add the reader part (but simplified to using a submodule), and finally there should be a solution for naming the language in a symbolic form --- but even for this there's no need for a package, it's likely easier with `link` or something similar.  Packages could be mentioned after all of this is done...